# Get input label on input.html.twig file

Tags: 8, theming, forms

I'm working on an input.html.twig file. I need the label name of the input for class and other reasons, but for some reason, I can't figure out how to grab it. I thought it would be part of the twig variables but I don't see it when I use kint().

So I tried using preprocess but it's not showing up.

```
function cougar_preprocess_form_element(&$vars){
$element =& $variables['element'];
$vars['test'] = 'test'; 
$vars['title'] = ['#markup' => $element['#title']];
}
```

I'm at a loss how to add the title to the input field twig file

Comment: If a class is all you need, would the input name work? `{{ element['#name'] | clean_class }}`

Comment: You almost there that you use ` $variables`  instead of  `$vars` ? change `$element =& $variables['element'];` by ` $element = $vars['element'];` you will get the the title from `$element['#title']`

Comment: Okay, so I should have used $variables instead of $vars. So that part worked. Then I used  clean_id and setAttribute to set it as the ID in the input field. Which is what I needed.